# Blazor | GetFromJsonAsyn error net::ERR_FAILED 200

Tags: c#, .net, http, razor, blazor

I'm tryting to to the following:

```
[Inject] public HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; } = default!;
public AzureActiveDirectoryUser[] AzureActiveDirectoryUsers { get; set; } = default!;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authenticationState = await authenticationStateTask;
        if (authenticationState.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            AzureActiveDirectoryUsers = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<AzureActiveDirectoryUser[]>(url); //this is line 52
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting the following error:

[image]

I don't really understand what it means.

What I'm trying to get is a JSON with usernames and emails (I have access to the URL and can verify that the data is there)

AzureActiveDirectoryUsers is just a class with an id and a mail.

(edit)
I used to have this error. But it just suddenly stopped.

[image]

Comment: Just because you can access a url directly in a browser/rest tool like Postman doesn't mean a script running on a webpage can. Look closer into the CORS error

Answer (score 1):

In OnInitializedAsync not everything is initalized on the page.

Move the code in OnAfterRenderAsync and call StateHasChanged if needed.

Comment: This is not working for me.